# Can I bind an arbitrary source IP to a socket?

Tags: c++, c, sockets, tcp, winsock

I have a TCP server running in an infinite loop like the following psuedo-code:

```
while (true)
{
    auto new_connected_socket = accept(listening_socket,...); 
    // Here it may block for a long time

    std::thread(fn_new_connection_handler, new_connected_socket);
}
```

In case of the administrator wants to stop the TCP server, it is indispensable to nicely break the infinite loop.

One way I thought of is using a special socket to connect to the TCP server. What makes the socket "special" is its source IP is "special", for example, 255.255.255.255 is obviously not a valid source IP.

If it is legal, then the client-side psuedo-code could be like the following:

```
auto special_socket = socket(...);
bind(special_socket, "255.255.255.255", ...);
connect(special_socket, tcp_server_addr, ...);
```

and the server-side psuedo-code could be as follows:

```
while (true)
{
    auto new_connected_socket = accept(listening_socket,...);
    // Here it may block for a long time

    if (IsSpecialSourceIp(new_connected_socket))
    {
        break; // Exit the server thread.
    }
    else
    {
        std::thread(fn_new_connection_handler, new_connected_socket);
    }
}
```

Is this soulution workable?

Comment: You may want to call `poll` before `accept`, and you could have another port for controlling your server.

Comment: In terms of performance, accept is cheap while poll is expensive. So I don't like poll.

Comment: Perhaps having a signal handler? Fire SIGTERM into the process

Comment: Why do you believe `poll` is expensive? It is used (or the older `select`) in a big lot of server code and in almost all event loops. IMHO it is the opposite: `poll` is cheap and optimized, and `accept` is expensive and usually blocking..

Comment: Block means "waiting" rather than "busy", so it's cheap. poll doesn't apply to this case. accept may block, during the blocking period, how do you break the block? That's just my initial issue.

Comment: `poll` is designed to monitor and limit the blocking period...

Comment: You seem to have a major misapprehension about how poll() works. It isn't a spin-loop and it is not expensive. Either poll(), select(), or a receive timeout on the socket is the answer to your problem. Not this non-existent source-address scheme.

Comment: @EJP, I've not been  working under *nix environments, so I use the term "poll" in its general meaning, rather than a certain system-provided function named "poll". Indeed, I don't know how the function "poll" works.

Comment: @xmllmx You should read the documentation of a certain API call rather than judging by it's name. Didn't your mama teach you the important lesson "never judge a book by it's cover"? ;-) Click on the links I placed in my answer yesterday to see how poll will work before going on with this discussion.

Comment: @xmlmx You were told to use a system function called poll(), and you stated unambiguously in reply that it is expensive. You were mistaken.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the [manpage of accept](http://linux.die.net/man/2/accept) (`man 2 accept`) You can mark the socket for nonblocking operation and use [select](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select) or [poll](http://linux.die.net/man/2/poll) to find out if a connection is waiting. Or even call accept repeatedly and check for EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK as return value with adequate pauses in between.

Of course select or poll are the better options as you don't need to "busy wait" and you get instant notification for new connections (lower latency). This is certainly a better solution compared to blocking the code ond doing some obscure socket magic to shutdown the server.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to use a "special" address, just set a flag in your app's memory somewhere that the `while` loop can look at, and then `connect()` a normal socket that is bound to any of the server machine's local IPs (let `connect()` handle the binding for you, you don't need to call `bind()` manually), eg:

```
bool shutting_down = false;
```

.

```
while (!shutting_down)
{
    auto new_connected_socket = accept(listening_socket,...); 
    // Here it may block for a long time

    if (shutting_down)
    {
        closesocket(new_connected_socket);
        break;
    }

    std::thread(fn_new_connection_handler, new_connected_socket);
}
```

.

```
shutting_down = true;

if (server is listening)
{
    sockaddr_in server_addr = {0};
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(my server port);
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_ddr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

    SOCKET wakeup_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    connect(wakeup_socket, (sockaddr*)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr));
    closesocket(wakeup_socket);
}
```

A better approach is to simply put your listening socket into non-blocking mode instead and use `select()` with a timeout in your loop so it can wake itself up periodically:

```
while (!shutting_down)
{
    fd_set rds;
    FD_ZERO(&rds);
    FD_SET(listening_socket, &rds);

    timeval t;
    t.tv_sec = 5;
    t.tv_usec = 0;

    if ((select(0, &rds, NULL, NULL, &t) > 0) && (!shutting_down))
    {
        auto new_connected_socket = accept(listening_socket,...); 
        std::thread(fn_new_connection_handler, new_connected_socket);
    }
}
```

Even better, use `WSACreateEvent()` and `WSAWaitForMultipleEvents()` instead of `select()`:

```
WSAEVENT hShutdownEvent = WSACreateEvent();
```

.

```
WSAEVENT hAcceptEvent = WSACreateEvent();
WSAEventSelect(listening_socket, hAcceptEvent, FD_ACCEPT);

while (true)
{
    WSAEVENT hEvents[2];
    hEvents[0] = hAcceptEvent;
    hEvents[1] = hShutdownEvent;

    DWORD dwRet = WSAWaitForMultipleEvents(2, hEvents, FALSE, INFINITE, FALSE);
    if (dwRet == WSA_WAIT_EVENT_0)
    {
        auto new_connected_socket = accept(listening_socket,...); 
        std::thread(fn_new_connection_handler, new_connected_socket);
    }
    else
        break;
}

WSACloseEvent(hAcceptEvent);
```

.

```
if (server is listening)
    WSASetEvent(hShutdownEvent);
```